# C for-loop variable assumes wrong (ginormous) values

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the smallest element in an array of 4 elements and its index; to do that I'm looping through the array and replacing a `smallest` variables with the current element if it is smaller. I'm doing the same for the index by replacing `smallestIdx` with the loop variable:

The 4 values for the array are read using scanf and that seems to be working fine:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double input[4];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    }
```

This is the part of the code I was talking about earlier:

```
    double smallest = input[0];
    int smallestIdx = 0;

    int c = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        printf("input[c] = %d; c = %i; smallest = %d; smallestIdx = %i\n",
        input[c], c, smallest, smallestIdx);
    
        if (input[c] < smallest) {
            smallest = input[c];
            smallestIdx = c;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
```

I have added a `printf` statement there to see what is going on before each iteration. The output is as follows:

```
input[c] = 1; c = 6422476; smallest = 0; smallestIdx = 1  
input[c] = 2; c = 237326259; smallest = 1; smallestIdx = 1
input[c] = 3; c = 6422200; smallest = 2; smallestIdx = 1  
input[c] = 4; c = 4200416; smallest = 3; smallestIdx = 3
```

As you can see, the entire code isn't working as intended, but what's most striking is `c` being something completely different from what it should be. I also have a feeling that one issue enables another one here. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `%d` is the format string to read an int. You're passing the address of a double. Undefined behavior. Same issue with `printf`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you, that answers my question. But why comment, and not simply answer?

Comment: What is the input type that you are working with?  %d is for int, not doubles.  However, it might work up until the decimal point.  Look at "man 3 sscanf" and "man 3 printf"

Comment: @T.Feix Can't speak for Retired Ninja, but I commented because I don't have enough information to be sure I understood you correctly.

Comment: Always enable compiler warnings to help avoid this sort of thing. Also, you probably want to avoid `%i` unless you have specific reasons to use it; use `%d` instead to print `int` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scanning and printing `double` variables using `%d` for an integer rather than `%lf`. Correct those issues and the program works as expected.

Compiling with warnings on would have identified these issues.

```
% cat test3.c              
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double input[4];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    }

    double smallest = input[0];
    int smallestIdx = 0;

    int c = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        printf("input[c] = %d; c = %i; smallest = %d; smallestIdx = %i\n",
        input[c], c, smallest, smallestIdx);
    
        if (input[c] < smallest) {
            smallest = input[c];
            smallestIdx = c;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
% gcc -Wall -Wextra test3.c
test3.c:9:21: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d", &input[i]);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~
               %lf
test3.c:18:9: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
        input[c], c, smallest, smallestIdx);
        ^~~~~~~~
test3.c:18:22: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
        input[c], c, smallest, smallestIdx);
                     ^~~~~~~~
test3.c:4:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
             ^
test3.c:4:26: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
                         ^
5 warnings generated.
```

After the fix, including the signature of `main`:

```
% cat test3.c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double input[4];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &input[i]);
    }

    double smallest = input[0];
    int smallestIdx = 0;

    int c = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        printf("input[c] = %lf; c = %i; smallest = %lf; smallestIdx = %i\n",
        input[c], c, smallest, smallestIdx);
    
        if (input[c] < smallest) {
            smallest = input[c];
            smallestIdx = c;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
% gcc -Wall -Wextra test3.c
%
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` format specifier is for `int` types, which have a different in-memory representation. Because it's placing an `int` representation into memory that you then treat as a `double`, it produces those strange values.

If you want to scan a `double`, you should be using `%lf` as the format specifier.

Some compilers can actually *warn* you about this, stating that there is a mismatch between specifier and variable.

Comment: This answer is correct too, but I accepted another one as it was more detailed.